# Modal Bootstrap não ultrapassar fim da página

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um **modal** bootstrap e nele eu exibo uma tabela, Porém quando essa tabela retornar muitos registros o modal acaba transbordando para fora da tela, E não da para ver o fim do modal como na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse problema incomoda pois tem registros que ficam abaixo escondido e não da para selecionar, No caso tem que diminuir o zoom para conseguir exibir o modal por completo.
No zoom fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de uma forma de esse modal não ultrapassar os limites da tela/monitor assim como faz para as margens superior e lateral, Já tentei com max-heigth mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Acho que tem que mexer é na altura da div "Clientes", e não na modal. Tenta setar um max-height na div "Clientes" no CSS ou direto na tag, tipo `<div style="max-height:...`

Comment: Consegui com max-height na classe modal-content usando max-heigth:100vh onde vh seria o limite da tela mesmo, no modal funcionaou agora a tabela esta estourando o modal, Preciso conseguir fazer ela ficar no limite mo modal tambem

Answer (score -1):

Coloca na classe CSS da *modal* o seguinte:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

ou

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Resolveu em partes, com o scroll não precisa dar o Zoom, Porém eu precisava que o modal se ajustasse para não ultrapassar o fim da tela e esse scroll ficasse na tabela

Comment: Verifica os height do css, coloca um min-height: 500px e height: auto.
Caso contrário vai ter que resolver com javascript.